# Member variable getting shared across multiple objects- python

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop

I created a class to store some variables and dictionary. Each object will have its own dictionary. However when I created a Class in certain way, it resulted in dictionary getting shared across all objects created. 
    When I tweaked the **init**, I was able to achieve what I wanted. I want to know why dictionary got shared across different objects and when and I would that be useful.

**Snippet 1:** (Where dictionary gets populated and shared across all object instances)

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y={}):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def set_y(self,key,value):
        self.y[key] = value
```

**Snippet 2**:(Where dictionary value is unique and not shared between member instances)

```
   class A(object):
        def __init__(self,x):
            self.x = x
            self.y = {}

        def set_y(self,key,value):
            self.y[key] = value
```

**Test Driver**:

```
l = "abcdefghijklmnopqrsqtuwxyz"
letter_list = []
node = None
for count, letter in enumerate(l,1):
    if node:
        letter_list.append(node)
    node = A(letter)
    node.set_y(letter,count)
```

I would like to know why dictionary got updated for all instances in first case and not for the second case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary is updated because of the way you used the default value in the `__init__` constructor.  In the first case, that empty dict is a single object; it is *not* a unique constructor for each new object.  It gets evaluated when the class is defined, and the *same* dict object sits there for each new object instantiated.  Very simply, the line

```
def __init__(self, x, y={}):
```

is executed *once*, when the function is defined, during the class definition.

In your second case, the initialization `self.y = {}` is in the body of the function, and so gets executed each time you instantiate a new object.  You can see the longer explanation in [this canonical posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument) on the topic.